# How to debug startup problem, if `--debug-init' has no effect

Tags: debugging, init-file

When I launch Emacs24 (in an Ubuntu machine) I get an error message in the init procedure.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/nivaca/.emacs':
```

But when I launch it with `emacs --debug-init` the debugger is not entered. How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Just to double check, do you have the same privileges when launching emacs with and without debugging ? It might be a launcher/terminal mismatch. Either way the `*Messages*` buffer should give you an idea of where the init barfs.

Comment: Yes, I believe so... But I will double check now. Anywhay, the `*Messages*` buffer gives me no clue.

Comment: What follows the final `:` in that warning message? If nothing, you might have uncovered an Emacs bug here. Presumably, that message is followed by some info about the error that occurred.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not enter the debugger from `--debug-init` in this case because the message is a **warning**, not an error message.  IOW, in spite of the text in the warning message, which speaks of an "*error*", from Emacs's point of view, **an error was not raised**. (Or at least not an error that is respected by `--debug-init` -- see `user-error`.)

Suggestions for debugging:

1. Recursively bisect your init file, to narrow down where the problem is. Do this by commenting-out 1/2 of it, then 3/4 of it, then 7/8, etc.  You can use `comment-region`, with and without a plain prefix arg (`C-u`), to comment and uncomment regions of text.
2. Add calls to `message` in your init file, to print information to let you know where the error occurs.

Use #1 especially if your init file is complex or it loads other libraries. #2 might suffice if your init file is simple and short.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [elisp-bug-hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter) to automatically bisect your init file.

> **Automated error hunting**
>
> If your Emacs init file signals an error during startup, but you don’t
>   know why, simply issue
>
> `M-x bug-hunter-init-file RET e`
>
> and The Bug Hunter will find it for you. Note that your init.el (or
>   .emacs) must be idempotent for this to work.
>
> **Interactive hunt**
>
> If Emacs starts up without errors but something is not working as it
>   should, invoke the same command, but choose the interactive option:
>
> `M-x bug-hunter-init-file RET i`
>
> The Bug Hunter will start a separate Emacs instance several times, and
>   then it will ask you each time whether that instance presented the
>   problem you have. After doing this about 5–12 times, you’ll be given
>   the results.

Comment: Looks promissing. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: The bug-hunter is awesome!  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it: there was a missing parenthesis in the `.emacs` file. However, the strange thing is that `--debug-init` couldn't spot it.

Comment: You can and should accept your own answer. It's a nice incentive for those like you who both find their own answer *and* come back and post it.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your Emacs, a `*Messages*` buffer is automatically opened. Go to this buffer to see what happened.