# Emacs without GUI adding extra text to opened files

Tags: debugging

Whenever I open a file using emacs **without** **gui** (`emacs --no-window-system`) it modifies the file with the following text:

```
12;rgb:0000/0000/0000
```

This text is inserted at the beginning of the file. How can I debug what is happening? How to prevent this from happening?

**UPDATES**:

This problems appears only when using **SSH**.

**DETAILS**:

The error appears in two cases **CentOS 5** and **CentOS 6**.

emacs **version** 24.5.2

The command I'm using to open the files is: `emacs --no-window-system file.txt`

The problems happens even when **disabling** all **customizations** ([How do I troubleshoot Emacs problems?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems)), e.g.: it persists when using (`emacs --no-window-system -Q file.txt`).

Comment: Just for knowing, does it work normally when you type `emacs -nw file.txt`?

Comment: In some themes (or snippets) there are conditionals to use in terminal vs GUI. It looks like one of them fails to set color and writes to a file instead. 1) If you use theme, try disabling it and if you don't look through your config and check if you have color-related commands there. Look closely for black. (000000)  2) Try looking at *Messages* buffer, there might be some warnings there.

Comment: @Nsukami_ Same issue happens with emacs -nw file.txt.

Comment: @RomanGrazhdan Yes, I'm using themes. Thanks for this suggestion. I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: @RomanGrazhdan Even disabling customization the error persists (using -Q flag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some general debugging tips

Try to get the debugger invoked when something tries to insert this text. This will give you a backtrace which should at least let you know what is doing the inserting, and hopefully that will in turn lead you towards how to work around the bug. Locate a *read-only* file `read-only-file.txt` (for example an OS file) and run

```
emacs --eval '(setq debug-on-error t debug-ignored-errors nil)' -nw read-only-file.txt
```

You should also determine whether the issue is with Emacs startup or with file opening. If you run plain `emacs -nw`, is the text inserted somewhere? If you open another file, is the text inserted into it as well? In the latter case, you can set `debug-on-error` and `debug-ignored-errors` after starting Emacs and open any file read-only with `M-x view-file`.

If you have trouble locating which package or which part of the init file is responsible for something, the tips in [How do I troubleshoot Emacs problems?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems) and [How to debug startup problem, if `--debug-init' has no effect](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/how-to-debug-startup-problem-if-debug-init-has-no-effect) should help.

### What is causing this

Given the text that's inserted, there's a good chance that the above generic tips will be unhelpful because they'll point at `self-insert-command`. The text looks like a response from a terminal when an application sends the [escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands) to query the terminal's color configuration. Normally, Emacs should send `\e]12;?\a` (where `\e` is the escape character, octal code 033, and `\a` is the bell character, octal code 007, which can be replaced by character 034), and the terminal replies `\e]12;rgb:0000/0000/0000\a` to say that the cursor color is black. It seems that something here is going wrong: Emacs is sending the color query command but not reading the response back. Your terminal configuration may be incorrect, or it may be a bug in the terminal code.

Check that the value of `TERM` is correct. If you have any code or package that tries to talk to the terminal directly, review it. Check in particular the package whose name is the same as the value of `TERM` — see the manual section about [terminal-specific initialization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Terminal_002dSpecific.html#Terminal_002dSpecific).

Unfortunately, I can't think of a simple way to set a breakpoint where something writes to the terminal. If you can't find the source of the problem on your own, there are some complicated ways, such as running Emacs under GDB, or running Emacs under an Expect script that sends SIGUSR2 when it sees the escape sequence in question.

To facilitate debugging, note that given the probable cause, it's likely that this text will be inserted every time you open a new terminal, so if you run the Emacs server you can set things up in an Emacs session and attach to a new terminal every time you want to test. This may help to debug: set a breakpoint at the beginning of the terminal setup function, and step through it until you find where it causes the problem (but note that the debugger's input/output may change the behavior of that part of the code).

Comment: I notice that this issue only appears if I'm launching emacs through SSH. The TERM variable is set to xterm.

Comment: Indeed it was an issue with my terminal. I installed a new version of the terminal I was using and it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded my mobaXterm ( from release 7 to 9.4 ) and this also fixed the "12;rgb:0000/0000/0000" problem for me.

Comment: same happens to me with mobaXterm 7.6
will upgrade now